# query expressions that return the full dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Say we have a dataframe `df` in Pandas, is there any way to define a [query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) expression so that I can still get the **full** dataframe?

In case it helps, I am using to using in a fashion similar ro:

```
if cond:
   condition = 'some expression'
else:
   condition = '<return everything>'


df.query(condition)
```

I tried:

- `df.query('True')`
- `df.query(True)`

with no luck.

also, `df.query(1)` seems to  retrieve only one record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little strange, but I guess you could do `index == index or index != index`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,np.nan]}, index=[10,20,np.nan])
>>> df
      A
 10   1
 20   2
NaN NaN
>>> df.query("index == index or index != index")
      A
 10   1
 20   2
NaN NaN
```

The `index != index` branch handles the case of NaNs.

Comment: @FabianRost: true, but won't work for object dtype indices, unfortunately.  I may use those more than other people, though.